# Why it displays character code instead of icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, unicode

I am trying to display symbol icon by pasting its unicode decimal code into the `content` attribute of the css `::before` pseudoclass.

When I insert it directly into html it works perfectly
`<div class="response__info" before-att = "&#11088" after-att = "7.7">`.

But When I do the same thing with javascript it shows me the code itself not the actual symbol
`infoElement.setAttribute('before-att', '&#x2b50');`

this is my css

```
response__info::before{
content: attr(before-att);
}
```

Comment: If you use `\u2B50` does it work?

Comment: yes it does, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unicode \u2B50

```js
document.querySelector('.response__info').addEventListener('click', event => event.target.setAttribute('before-att', '\u2B50'))
```

```css
.response__info::before{
content: attr(before-att);
}
```

```html
<div class="response__info" before-att = "X">Hello</div>
```